# How to compare 2 linked lists in c++ and put matching data into another linked list

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list

I want to compare two linked lists that contain book titles and then create a new linked list that only has the matching titles from the original lists. Currently I have already created both linked lists and can output both in alphabetical order. The problem comes when I try to compare and create the updated list with the matching titles.

I have tried to create a recursive function that takes in both lists as parameters and will call itself and move the second list to the next node if the titles don't match.

If they both match, then it again calls itself, but moves both lists up a node.

I'm still pretty new on using linked lists and recursion, but I feel like I'm on the right track. All of my other functions are working, I'm just not sure how to make this work and also how to call it in my main function.

```
Node *compare(Node *h, Node *j) {
  Node* h_curr = h;
  Node* j_curr = j;
  Node* new_node;
  Node* updated_list = NULL;
  while ((h_curr->next != NULL) || (j_curr->next != NULL)) {
    if (h_curr->data != j_curr->data) { // if not equal, then move j_head to the next link 
      compare(h_curr, j_curr->next);
        //j_curr = j_curr->next;
    }
    else {
      updated_list->data = h_curr->data;
      new_node = newNode(updated_list->data);
      return updated_list;
      updated_list = updated_list->next;

      compare(h->next, j->next);
    }

  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Comment: From *output both in alphabetical order* can we assume the data is sorted? Unsorted data is gross. N-squared gross.

Comment: Yes, both lists are sorted before being called into the comparison function.

Comment: A cleaner iterative way of doing this is via the "merge" function(as used in merge_sort): https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-two-sorted-arrays/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

//assumed node structure
struct Node{

    Node(std::string str, Node* ptr = nullptr):data(str), next(ptr){}

    std::string data{};
    Node* next{};

};

//The following is your rucresive function
void compare(Node* & first, Node* & second, Node* & match) {

    if(!first || !second ) return;//base case

    if ( first -> data < second -> data) compare(first -> next, second, match ); 
    else if ( first -> data > second -> data) compare(first , second -> next, match); 
    else{//match found
        match = new Node{ first -> data};
        compare(first , second -> next, match -> next); 
    }
}

//To disply the result (recursive function)
void display(Node* & root){

    if(!root) return;
    std::cout<<root->data<<" ";
    display( root-> next);

}


//To test
int main(){

    Node* first = new Node{"aaa"};
    first->next=new Node{"ccc"};
    first->next->next=new Node{"ccc1"};
    first->next->next->next=new Node{"ccc3"};
    first->next->next->next->next=new Node{"ccc4"};
    first->next->next->next->next->next=new Node{"ddd"};


    Node* second = new Node{"baaa"};
    second->next=new Node{"ccc"};
    second->next->next=new Node{"ccc1"};
    second->next->next->next=new Node{"ccc2"};
    second->next->next->next->next=new Node{"ccc4"};

    Node* res;
    compare(first, second, res);
    display(res);


}
```

Comment: Seems to have worked! I was debating on whether I should have put in a 3rd parameter for the function, so I'm glad to see that I was thinking in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexHernandez U R welcome. U can also use a function with only two parameters and then call the function in the solution using the new one after defining the third parameter in the new one.